# ASP.NET Beginner (Hello World)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

For now I'm watching youtube video, and in the very fast video about Hello World I'm already having problems, because after creating a Web Form (I'm using Visual Studio 2017), I added a textbox to the aspx file that now contains:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.designer.cs" Inherits="HelloWorlds.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="item1" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But after adding this, in the youtube video in the cs file it automatically generates a .Page_Load method, but in my IDE, I don't why, it isn't generated automatically, so I manually added the method and code, but after executing it, the textbox is empty. Can anyone help me to understand first of all why in my IDE it doesn't create the Page_Load() method automatically, and then why after adding it manually it still not working?

This is my .designer.cs file:

```
namespace HelloWorlds {


public partial class WebForm1 {

    /// <summary>
    /// form1 control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm form1;

    /// <summary>
    /// item1 control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox item1;

    void Page_Load()
    {
        item1.Text = "Test001!";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You don't derive your page class from _System.Web.UI.Page_

Comment: I added ": System.Web.UI.Page" to the class WebForm1, but still it is not working

Comment: If you're new to ASP.NET development, why start with Web Forms, a dying framework?

Comment: @mason So where do you think should I start? Can you suggest me any website/documentation/book and argument to start? I have programming abilities but I never used ASP.NET, I'm proficient at Java, HTML, CSS and other languages. By the way I started with those because it's the first thing I found on youtube, I don't know where is better to start, I'm open to any suggestion. Thanks very much!

Comment: Well MVC is clearly more popular, though the modern thing to do is learn a front end client side framework and a back end framework that it can talk to.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is a back end framework, right? Which front end framework do you suggest ?

Comment: Do your own research. There's plenty of comparisons out there.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, I was editing the .aspx.designer.cs instead of the .aspx.cs file.